# Pandas import module missing in VSCode

Tags: python, pandas

I am having issues with importing the pandas library into my project on VS Code. I have pandas installed on my machine and my machine is currently running python 3.9.12. I tried changing the interpreter in my IDE from 3.10.64 to 3.9.12 but I cannot find the path to it. I was wondering if there was anything else I should try/do to help fix this issue. Thank you!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you set the path using your environment variables as [shown here](https://www.alphr.com/pip-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command/)

Then, using pip, just simply do `!pip install pandas` in order to have the pandas path set correctly automatically. I understand you may have installed it manually but this may help.